# substitution with regex pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like `longstring-abc{something goes here}`, and I want to replace the part inside the braces after `abc` with `replacement`. (So it should be `longstring-abc{replacement}`. I'm trying to use the `re.sub` function:

```
re.sub(r'abc\{(.*)\}', r'replacement', r'mylongstring-abc\{def\}')
```

So I'm trying to look for the pattern `abc\{(.*)\}` and replace what's inside `(...)` with `replacement`. But this just returns me the original string. How can I make it correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, a glitch: You don't need to escape curly braces in an RE; they stand for themselves. Also, if you escape them in the string itself, you're inserting *actual* backslashes in the string, and your RE would have to match them as well.

Second, for your problem: Match just enough of the string to ensure that you don't match by mistake. The entire thing will be replaced, so if you only want to replace inside the braces, use a group to capture and reuse the part you're *not* changing:

```
re.sub(r'(abc){.*}', r'\1{replacement}', 'mylongstring-abc{def}')
```

Or, if the "abc" part is fixed, you could simply include it literally:

```
re.sub(r'abc{.*}', r'abc{replacement}', 'mylongstring-abc{def}')
```

Note that you don't need a group around `.*` unless you're using it in the replacement string.

Incidentally, your pattern will match too much if there is another closing brace on the same line. To stop at the *first* closing brace, use `r"(abc){[^}]*}"` or `r"(abc){.*?}"`. The latter is a "non-greedy" star: It matches as little as possible.